# How to get Current Hour and Minute as seperate values

Tags: php

How do i get the current Hour and Minutes on a users PC as separate values in PHP and echo them separately?

I want to echo the hour and minute that is current in different locations.

Thanks!

edit: Since we cant do the user time, lets do server time.

Comment: PHP by its self is not going to know anything about the time on a user's PC because its running server-side before anything hits the PC

Comment: Okay let me correct that then. Lets do the Server

Comment: `$hour = date('H'); $minute = date('i');`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$dt = new DateTime();

echo $dt->format('H');
echo $dt->format('i');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it's easy

```
echo date('H');  // is current hour 24 hour clock
echo date('h');  // is current hour 12 hour clock
echo date('ha');  // is current hour 12 hour clock with am/pm
echo date('i');  // is current minute
```

Results are if time is 19/06/2015 18:54:40

```
18
06
06pm
54
```

Answer (score 2):

12 hour clock

```
<?php echo date("g"); echo date("i");?>
```

24 hour clock w/o leading zero

```
<?php echo date("G"); echo date("i");?>
```

24 hour clock w/ leading zero

```
<?php echo date("H"); echo date("i");?>
```

Your best resource is the PHP.net manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

date("H") - for hour (00-23);
date("i") - for minute (00 - 59)

Answer (score 0):

When using a Time Zone you can use this

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
echo "Today is : " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
echo "The time is in New York: " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

Today is : 2015/06/19

The time is in New York: 03:06:30pm